# Picking date with CakePhp and AngularJS: placeholder not shown

Tags: angularjs, cakephp

I am using cakephp and angularjs for picking date and it works fine. But the placeholder is not shown in the inputbox:

```
<div
    ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl"
    class="form-group form-inline appt_form-date"
    ng-init="setmaildate = ' '"
    id="sched_mail"
>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('EmailerFrontend.date', array(
        'placeholder' => 'Date',
        'label' => false,
        'type' => 'text',
        'ng-model' => 'setmaildate',
        'datepicker-popup' => "{{formats[5]}}",
        'is-open' => "opened",
        'min-date' => "minDate",
        'max-date' => "maxDate",
        'datepicker-options' => "dateOptions",
        'date-disabled' => "disabled(date, mode)",
        'ng-required' => "true" ,
        'close-text' => "Close",
        'ng-click' => 'open($event)',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'div' => false
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more descriptive and moved the actual question into the body. I also indented the code properly. Good luck!